# Solving $2\log(n!) - n\log n \le 2n\log n$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I need to prove that:
$$2log(n!) - nlogn \le 2nlogn$$

Can I say that:
$$2log(n!) - nlogn \le 2log(n!) = 2\cdot \Sigma^n_{i=1} log(i) \color{red}{\le} 2\cdot\Sigma^n_{i=1} log(n)$$
$$\Sigma^n_{i=1} log(n) \le 2n\cdot logn$$

Is the $\color{red}{red}$ inequality holds? I really can't tell if this is right. Would love for some help. Thank you.

Comment: Add the missing $2$ in front of the sum after the red inequality and yes, you're done. Why aren't you convinced by this step, by the way? $\log$ is a strictly increasing function, so there is absolutely no hesitation/doubt to have.

Comment: I wasn't sure because of the Sigma. I was afraid I was doing something wrong. Thank you for clarifying it to me.

Comment: If $i \le n$ then $\log(i) \le \log(n)$.  And for a finite sum if $a_i \le k$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le \sum_{i=1}^n k$.  So yes, this is acceptable.  (But be careful if it is an *in*finite sum... such things are not always possible [although in this case it would be])

Comment: Be careful about your last line, it is false and unneeded. At the point of the red inequality, you are done :)

Answer (score 3):

For $n\ge 1,$ we have

$$1\le n!\le n^n$$
thus
$$(n!)^2\le (n^n)^2\le (n^n)^3$$

taking logarithm, we get

$$2\ln(n!)\le 3n\ln(n)$$

and
$$2\ln(n!)-n\ln(n)\le 2n\ln(n)$$
done.